# sr-feuser-register with or without deprecated rsaauth

Tags: dependencies, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

EXT:rsaauth is [deprecated since TYPO3 CMS 9.1](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.1/Deprecation-81852-DeprecatedUsageOfEXTrsaauth.html), but still a dependency of sr_feuser_register's [latest version (6.0.2)](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sr_feuser_register/), which is stable and compatible with 9 LTS.

I'm wondering if I should install the deprecated rsaauth or If I should force sr_feuser_register to install without rsaauth on TYPO3 CMS 9.5.4 by editing the extension's ext_emconf. It's a **https** website. Would sr_feuser_register work without rsaauth and be just as secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension `rsaauth` has been deprecated because using `https://` is more secure and does a better job in general.

If you are **not** using a secure connection, `rsaauth` is still the way to go.

---

Regarding your question: Yes having https & rsaauth still works and is fine, however there is no *additional* security gain.

Comment: Thanks! The connection is secure, so there's no need for me to use rsaauth except the dependencie of sr_feuser_register. Do you know if it needs rsaauth for technical reasons, or if the dependency is just there to make sure that http-sites send encrypted data?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is just there for historical reasons

Comment: I have asked the developer Stanislas and he just told me that I can use sr_feuser_register without it safely, but if the site is not using SSL, rssauth is required. He said perhaps, the requirement for rsauth should be removed. But, then SSL would be required. Since rsauth is still available, he was planning to remove the requirement only in TYPO3 CMS 10.

Comment: Stanislas send me some additional infos regarding this: If you use either the auto-login feature on email confirmation or if you use the invitation feature, then rssauth is required (acceptation of the invitation performs auto-login so that the user may select a password).